# Can we save searches or have tag profiles?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

I have many diverse tags that I favorited, but I'm often in the mood to only look at specific groups. For example, [java] [spring]... or if I'm in a CI mood: [jenkins] [maven]..., or in testing mood: [selenium] [automated-tests]...

While I can craft search urls for each of these, they are a pain, especially with a lot of tags. I'd like to be able to save these searches to my account. Or call these "tag profiles" or "tag groups" that I can choose so I'm only seeing those tags I'm in the mood to see.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/filters.

Comment: well dang, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to save these searches to my account.

You can already do that! :)

[Start here](https://stackexchange.com/filters).

Worth to mention, this appears when editing your favorite tags on any site:

> [image]

This let you create groups of tags on one or more sites, creating a default filter based on your favorite tags.

To create a new filter, just click "New filter":

> [image]

And you can choose what tags/sites you want to take questions from. You can then choose to send you the results via email in addition to seeing them in there.

This is all saved to your network account.

Comment: Can a filter only include a single tag?

Comment: @Raven of course, here is an [example](https://stackexchange.com/filters/65715/cakephp). But for single tag on single site, you better subscribe to it on the site itself.

Comment: Hah. My wording was confusing. I would be interested in saving a query like `[bash] or [vi] `. It looks like I can't enter a boolean or multiple tags in the filter.

Comment: @Raven oh, I'm afraid this is not possible